# Posting a dictionary to .net core 3.1. API

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I want to post the following DTO to a .NET Core API:

```
{
    "Name": "Foo",
    "Street": "Bar",
    "DynamicInfo": {
        "MetadataAsString": "23423",
        "MetadataAsInt": 2,
        "MetadataAsBool": true,
        "SomeOtherValues": "blub"
    }
}
```

The class I want to map this in C# looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> DynamicInfo { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that I am using two static properties (Name and Street), but I also want to post some dynamic data.
I expect the dynamic data to be written in a dictionary, but unfortunately this does not work.
The result I am getting in my debugger is a little confusing:

[image]

So the values arrive successful, but are in a strange format... I dont know how to even access the values.
How can I convert this to just a normal dictionary, containing objects?

Comment: is the list DynamicInfo somehow limited? I mean can you have a class DynamicInfo, that will hold all different possible value and based the serialisation on the type?

Comment: If you have data in the debugger (and I would say that does look like your input data), then you do have the data in a dictionary. Did you try `myFoo.DynamicInfo["MetadataAsString"]` and did you get an object that is a string with the value of `"23423"`?

Comment: No... its absolutely flexible.

Comment: @crashmstr: In this case I get: "ValueKind = String : "23423"". And I am still not sure what this is...

Comment: Not just in the debugger, but accessing it in code? Plus, you told it to be "Object", so to do anything with it, you need to check what type it is to use it as a number or a boolean, or a string.

Comment: Found it out, check my solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The resulting object (ValueKind=String: 23423) is nothing else than a JSONElement. I did not understand this before.
This JSONElement has an enum that tells me what datatype I have, so I can use this to map my Dictionary of JSONElements to another dictionary of "real" objects.

```
var newDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var d in obj.DynamicInfo)
            {
                object obt;
                string key = d.Key;
                var a = enterprise.BasicInformation.TryGetValue(key, out obt);
                if (obt == null) continue;
                var doc = (JsonElement)obt;

                string myString = null;
                bool? myBool = null;
                int? myInteger = null;
                double? myFloatNumber = null;
                if (doc.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String)
                {
                    myString = doc.ToString();
                }

                if (doc.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.True)
                {
                    myBool = true;
                }
                if (doc.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.False)
                {
                    myBool = false;
                }
                if (doc.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Number)
                {
                    double floatNumber;
                    doc.TryGetDouble(out floatNumber);
                    if ((floatNumber % 1) == 0)
                    {
                        myInteger = (int)floatNumber;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myFloatNumber = floatNumber;
                    }
                }
                if (myString != null)
                {
                    newDic.Add(key, myString);
                }
                if (myBool != null)
                {
                    newDic.Add(key, myBool);
                }
                if (myInteger != null)
                {
                    newDic.Add(key, myInteger);
                }
                if (myFloatNumber != null)
                {
                    newDic.Add(key, myFloatNumber);
                }
            }
```

The code might not be perfect - I will try to optimize it. But it does what it should.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that would not depend on your use case, I would use 2 objects. 1 for client input and 1 that has validated input. The client input object would contain a `Dictionary<string,string>`. And the validated input can contain your `Dictionary<string,object>` if its still something you intend to use.

If you use this approach. During validation of the client input, you could use `bool.TryParse(DynamicInfo["MetadataAsBool"], out YourBoolean)`. Then simply add the `YourBoolean` to your new `Dictionary<string,object> objectDictionary` like `objectDictionary.Add("BoolMetadata", YourBoolean)`

Comment: But this forces my client to convert all int and bool values to strings... but I already thought about this solution too...

Comment: Well, in the spirit of best practice, I see 2 options available to you. Either use a strongly typed object and let type serialization do the work, instead of a `Dictionary<string,object>` representing the data request. Or manually validate strings in a `Dictionary<string,string>` object with `TryParse`.